# How to display names and percentages in a pie chart legend using mpchartlib

Tags: android, charts

I want to display a pie chart like [this](https://i.embed.ly/1/image?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.klipfolio.com%2Fimages%2Fsaas%2Fansweredadvancedpie.png&key=afea23f29e5a4f63bd166897e3dc72df)

Please note that I do not want to display the names of items and theirs values inside of  each slice because I am having allot of items and when I displaying all names into slices the names and values aren't intelligible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you of not
but you can pass the value to a TextView and per my knowledge, I only can change the TextView value on method `public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h)`

I'm doing it like this

```
desc.setText(code.get(h.getXIndex()) + " - " + name.get(h.getXIndex()) + ", Area: " + area.get(h.getXIndex()));
```

where code, name, and area is `ArrayList<String> name, code, area;`

Comment: thanks allot for your answer. I already solve the issue by creating a layout with the needed components.I will check your answer and I will send you a feedback as soon as possible.